HTML background image on iOS mail is incorrectly positioned
I have HTML content like this in my email (a webP image, and a fallback to JPG if the client doesn't support it):
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    #container
    {
        height: 960px;
        width: 640px;
        background: url("https://i.ibb.co/D5HD2v7/pexels-aibek-skakov-418917601-29902918-1.jpg") no-repeat;
        background-size: 640px 960px;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qWNg8ZT/pexels-aibek-skakov-418917601-29902918-1.webp">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

This renders fine on most email clients including Outlook & Gmail web apps, MacOS Mail, etc and looks like this:

On iOS mail & iOS Outlook, however, the background image doesn't properly position within the div, so once you scroll down you see the background image stretched out:

How do I fix this?  It doesn't seem to be an issue with iOS safari, as the HTML in iOS safari looks fine.  It seems to be an email-specific rendering issue.

I have run your provided code in iOS it it works fine just like first image. Image was not repeating. I tried in safari with iOS 18 on iPhone.

@Meet yes, it works fine on Safari on iOS.  It seems to be an iOS Mail-specific issue.

You are specifying a fixed size for your background and you also aren’t telling it to not repeat.
If I understand your requirement correctly, you want:
background-size: cover

the background image is actually the same size as the div, but i specified the height & width just in case.  I tried your suggestion with 'background-size: cover' but the issue still persists.
